# Excel Dynamic List with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an excel inventory Worksheet with a Dynamic Data Validation for my Dropdown list. I don't know why exactly, but the minute I add an extra Row in the sheet where the validation occurs, I have the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

My code is fired BeforeDoubleClick

```
Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
```

This is the piece of code which keeps on giving me an error at the Formula1: section. I am not sure why, but it only happens the minute I add an extra line in the actite worksheet where the action is triggered.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("List_Items")) Is Nothing Then
                    Var = CurSheetName & "!" & ActiveDynamicRange
                    With Selection.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & Var
                        .IgnoreBlank = True
                        .InCellDropdown = True
                        .InputTitle = ""
                        .ErrorTitle = ""
                        .InputMessage = ""
                        .ErrorMessage = ""
                        .ShowInput = True
                        .ShowError = True
                    End With
                End If
```

The Var variable is set up as follow:

```
Var = CurSheetName & "!" & ActiveDynamicRange
```

which corresponds to: Inventory_October_2016!$C$3:$C$3

If I remove the line, it works fine. But the minute I add a new line, it starts bugging. Does anybody have an idea why please?

Thanky you.

Comment: `" Operator:=" is missing the dot qualifier.

Comment: So `ActiveDynamicRange` is a fixed String `$C$3:$C$3`? Why not just use a Named Range to replace `Inventory_October_2016!$C$3:$C$3` (which is not dynamic at all) and use that name? e.g. `, Formula1:="=NewNamedRange"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the Reply. The exemple of Inventory_October_2016!$C$3:$C$3 is only for my current situation  but it's not always the case. If another Item is added to the list, it will be Inventory_October_2016!$C$3:$C$4, Inventory_October_2016!$C$3:$C$5 and so on.

Comment: @PatriK The range is created base on the number of non empty cells

 `items = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(CurSheetName).Range("ITEM_NO"))`

`If items > 1 Then
              FirstCell = Sheets(CurSheetName).Range("ITEM_NO").Cells(1, 1).Address
              LastCell = Sheets(CurSheetName).Range("ITEM_NO").Cells(items, 1).Address
              ActiveDynamicRange = FirstCell & ":" & LastCell
           Else
              FirstCell = Sheets(CurSheetName).Range("ITEM_NO").Cells(1, 1).Address
              ActiveDynamicRange = FirstCell & ":" & FirstCell
           End If`